# Vb.net Chart.SaveImage doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, image, charts, save, userform

I am very puzzled on how it is that my chart in a userform doesn't get saved.

I double checked: `myChart` is a standard .NET framework 4.5 `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`.

I tried:

```
myUserform.myChart.SaveImage(myFolder & "Pic.png", Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Png)
```

and:

```
myUserform.myChart.SaveImage(myFolder & "Pic.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Non of these works and instead throws: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

For what it's worth, my chart is a polar chart with 3 series, some of which can also not be enabled. The chart has also a title and a legend.

Comment: Does `myFolder` end with a \?

Comment: Yes. The full string would be something like: `C:\myFolder\Pic.png`

Comment: Does the folder also exist, and does your app have permission to write to that path?

Comment: Both positive. The folder is selected from the user (so it must exist) and I can write in that path (tried both things before)